# Empty block in recursion base case

Tags: javascript, recursion

I wrote a recursive function to uncheck all menu nodes. It works well, but I need to know if it is right to leave empty block inside `if (nodes[i].children.length === 0)` base case.

Is there a better design choice?

The function:

```
function uncheck_all_tree (nodes) {
  var i, n, n_dom_el;

  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].children.length === 0) {
      // recursion bottom;
    } else {
      uncheck_all_tree(nodes[i].children); 
    }

    // pop nodes from recursion stack
    n = tree.jstree('get_node', nodes[i]);
    n_dom_el = document.getElementById(n.id + '_anchor');
    if (n_dom_el !== null) {
      console.log(n.id + '_anchor');
      n_dom_el.className = 'jstree-anchor';
    }
    n.state.checked = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More things that can be improved:

#### Variable declarations

To allow for easier understanding you should declare variables as close as possible to their usage (even though it's semantically no different)

Additionally IIRC javascript variables are usually `camelCase` and not `snake_case`. Furthermore it's useful to write out variable names instead of shortening them as much as possible. This reduces cognitive load and makes the code easier to read.

#### General case

Simply through the way your code works, I'm dead sure that you don't even need that if-statement you have there. It's superfluous, because it's already working for the general case. If your `nodes` have 0 elements, the for-loop is not executed and the "recursion bottom" is reached.

#### "Final" result:

```
function uncheck_all_tree (nodes) {
    for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {
        uncheck_all_tree(nodes[i].children); 
        var node = tree.jstree('get_node', nodes[i]);
        var nDomElement = document.getElementById(n.id + '_anchor');
        if (nDomElement !== null) {
            console.log(node.id + '_anchor');
            nDomElement.className = 'jstree-anchor';
        }
        node.state.checked = false;
    }
}
```

In addition to that [Ismael Miguel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/53773/ismael-miguel) has suggested in a comment to use `Array.forEach.call(nodes[i].children, function(node) { [...] });` to further improve performance. More information on how that works can be found at the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: `jslint` suggest me to declare variables outside of the loop declaration and body. As far as I remember, it is because in JS, a variable is inside the function scope, not inside `for () {}` loop scope. Am I not right? Plus, I don't see the recursion (the function calling itself) in your final example.

Comment: Whoops I skipped that line.. I did mention that it makes no semantic difference for the variable declarations. This hints at the block scoping you mention

Comment: Now it looks good. And what about the variables scope? Where is it better to declare them?

Comment: declare variables as close as possible to their usage to reduce cognitive load. In Javascript it doesn't make an actual difference for the lifetime scope, but it's good practice either way.

Comment: Just 3 small things: 1- You should store the length on a variable on your `for` loop: `for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)`. It would look *like* this: `for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++)`. This makes transversing a lot faster. 2- The variable `n` should be called `node`. 3- You have double-quotes on `n.id + "_anchor"` while you have single-quotes through the code. Other than that, you can use `Array.forEach.call(nodes[i].children, function(){ [...] })` instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel why not write an answer of your own?

Comment: @Vogel612 Because it is an improvement on **your** answer. On it's own, it would be a bad review. You say to do not shorten names, yet you have a variable `n` (`node`). The `for` loop is an improvement that most people don't care about, but hurts performance later on the line. And the double quotes could have been an oversight.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel sounds reasonable. Edited the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Vogel612 You're welcome. I would double-upvote if I could. Also, It is a good idea to link to the MDN page about the `Array.forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach (it has a polyfill for ... IE ...). Also, I've made a small mistake. The right way is `Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes[i].children, function(node) { [...] });`. The `[...]` would be the content inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Storing the length as it's own variable is a pre-mature optimisation and makes the code harder to read because it no longer looks like a simple for loop. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9592751/1036813 And in older browsers Array.prototype.forEach either doesn't exist or is decidedly the slowest way to loop.

Comment: @Blaine I disagree. Try opening your console on this page, with the following code: http://pastebin.com/5WgVnwRb. You can replace `$('*')` with `Array(1e6)`. On Firefox, the first method takes half the time! I saw an interesting result: storing the variable before *can* be slower *sometimes* , for small element count (<2000). And yes, the `forEach` may not exist on ... IE ..., but you have a polyfill that uses a modifier of the method used on http://stackoverflow.com/a/5349485, available on MDN.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way, don't know why I didn't see it the first time :-)

There is no need for the empty `if () {}` block. The recursive call is needed only if there are children nodes `nodes[i].children.length > 0`. And all nodes are unchecked when we are moving back from recursion.

Final result:

```
function uncheck_all_tree (nodes) {
  var i, node, nodeDomEl;

  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].children.length > 0) {
      uncheck_all_tree(nodes[i].children); 
    }
    // recursion bottom;
    // pop nodes from recursion stack
    node = tree.jstree('get_node', nodes[i]);
    nodeDomEl = document.getElementById(node.id + '_anchor');
    if (nodeDomEl !== null) {
      nodeDomEl.className = 'jstree-anchor';
    }
    node.state.checked = false;
  }
}
```